# Cache feed and only refresh when feed is changed

Tags: php, caching, feed

Over at [rsscache](http://www.rsscache.com/howworks.aspx) they have a way of refreshing the cache only when the feed has changed. Unfortunately its .Net.

I would like to know what approach I should take to achieve this in php.

How are changes in the feed detected? Simply by a timestamp (time node in the beginning of the feed)?

My feed would be a yahoo pipe that has mixed many feeds together. So either the yahoo feed must generate a combined timestamp, or my cache mechanism must automagically detect if the pipe has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

- Store when the content you have cache was last stored (read the server's `Last-modified` header).
- Make conditional GET requests (send the header `If-modified-since`).

The server will either respond with `200` (OK) and the content or `304` (Not Modified) and an empty response body.

See [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Comment: detailed explenation;
http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/how_does_simplepie_s_caching_http_conditional_get_system_work